# Paperclip attachments with dynamic style sizes from Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Using Rails 2, I try to separate different, dynamic image sizes trough another Model from the Paperclip-Model. My current approach, using a Proc, looks the following:

```
class File < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sizes, :class_name => "FileSize"
  has_attached_file(
    :attachment,
    :styles => Proc.new { |instance| instance.attachment_sizes }
  )

  def attachment_sizes
    sizes = { :thumb => ["100x100"] }
    self.sizes.each do |size|
      sizes[:"#{size.id}"] = ["#{size.width}x#{size.height}"]
    end
    sizes
  end
end

class FileSize < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to    :file

  after_create  :reprocess
  after_destroy :reprocess

  private

  def reprocess
    self.file.attachment.reprocess!
  end
end
```

Everything seems to work out fine but apparently no styles are processed and no image is being created.

Did anyone manage doing stuff like this?

**-- Update --**

Obviously the method attachment_sizes on instance sometimes is not defined for # - but shouldn't instance actually be #?
For me this looks like altering instance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple. `instance` in my first example Proc is an instance of Paperclip::Attachment. As I want to call a `File` method, one has to get the calling instance inside the Proc:

```
Proc.new { |clip| clip.instance.attachment_sizes }
```

`instance` represents `File`-instance in the given example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have everything working with paperclip, such that you have uploaded an image and now the proc is just not working.

It should work. Try not putting the size in an array.

You are doing this

```
sizes = { :thumb => ["100x100"] }
```

But I have it where I'm not putting the size in an arry

```
sizes = { :thumb => "100x100" }
```

Give that a try :)

Comment: Hi, thank's for the quick answer. I tried to isolate my issue a little more with a question-update. On the other hand I can't actually check wether your idea works. But actually everything worked great beforehand, even though I used an array

Comment: what do you mean you cannot check if my idea works, just remove the array brackets and upload :)

Comment: I meant that it works the same way - so it doesn't have an effect on my issue ^^ thanks, though!