# paperclip watermark processor unrecognized option `-crop' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, paperclip

Just trying to add watermarks to images via paperclip and imagemagick. Here is gist with my watermark processor:
https://gist.github.com/xamenrax/6164246

my model is:

```
  CONVERT_OPTION_PREFIX = "-background transparent -compose Copy -gravity center -extent"

  has_attached_file :image,
            :processors => [:watermark],
            :styles => {
              :slider => { geometry: "480x226#", watermark_path: "#{Rails.root}/public/images/watermarks/medium/watermark.png" },
              :big => { geometry: "670x426#", watermark_path: "#{Rails.root}/public/images/watermarks/big/watermark.png" },
              :medium => { geometry: "155x160#", watermark_path: "#{Rails.root}/public/images/watermarks/thumb/watermark.png" },
              :thumb => { geometry: "106x160#", watermark_path: "#{Rails.root}/public/images/watermarks/thumb/watermark.png" },
              :wide_medium => { geometry: "220x150#", watermark_path: "#{Rails.root}/public/images/watermarks/thumb/watermark.png" },
              :square => { geometry: "100x102#", watermark_path: "#{Rails.root}/public/images/watermarks/square/watermark.png" }
            },
            convert_options: { slider: "#{CONVERT_OPTION_PREFIX} 480x226", big: "#{CONVERT_OPTION_PREFIX} 670x426", medium: "#{CONVERT_OPTION_PREFIX} 155x160", wide_medium: "#{CONVERT_OPTION_PREFIX} 220x150", square: "#{CONVERT_OPTION_PREFIX} 100x102"  }
```

But when saving image I get error:

```
Command 'composite -gravity SouthEast '/Users/xamenrax/projects/handmadefood/public/images/watermarks/medium/watermark.png' '/var/folders/26/0fjt3lc101x1714cc5xxkfgc0000gn/T/pro20130806-1681-i05d3l20130806-1681-1yvw0r1' -resize '480x' -crop '480x226+0+127' +repage '/var/folders/26/0fjt3lc101x1714cc5xxkfgc0000gn/T/pro20130806-1681-i05d3l20130806-1681-1yvw0r1'' returned 1. Expected 0
```

What's the problem? Is -crop `'480x226+0+127'` invalid option?

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280748/define-paperclip-style-sizes-dynamicaly

Comment: Thx for you answer! But I dont change size of images dynamically.

Comment: is it working when you tried `convert_options: { slider: "-crop 480x226+0+127"}` ?